Need to get the table(Cont.) in caption of table that spans across mutiple pages
I need to get the Table(number)(Cont.), in the caption of a table that spans across more than one page. I tried using the \continuedfloat but I am only getting the table(number) and not the (Cont.) term with it. Heres what I tried:
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{}
\label{tab:table4}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
\toprule
....
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]\ContinuedFloat
\centering
\caption{}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
\hline
.....
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}

Heres my preamble:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{comment}
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont=bf}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=bf}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
%\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=numeric-comp ,
sorting=ynt
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}


Have you looked into the longtable package?  Off-topic: never use \resizebox (nor adjustbox) on a table.

@Teepeemm No, I've never used the longtable package. Besides, I am getting good enough tables with the current code but the only issue is the one I mentioned. The funny thing is, my friend used the same method, and she's getting the required results but somehow I am not. Not sure where I am getting it wrong.
